# Timer with alerts-Clarity

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am using Clarity vmware for html in Angular2.

When I show alerts if the User click in "x" close that alert, then during all execute the my program doesn't show messages (because user did click in 'x').

So I disabled close with 'x':

```
[clrAlertClosable]="false"
```

But then I get multiples alerts in html "alert-danger", alert.succes " etc. Because I can't close alerts.

I searched in https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/alerts#guidelines but don't exist timer for alerts ...

How Can I it ? 
Thanks.

Comment: There are no built in timers for Alerts to auto-close with our Angular component. However, I'm not clear what your issue is or what you want it to do exactly?

Comment: when you do click in 'x' the Alert the clarity, never , never , never, 
another alert is shown because  you did click in 'x' , I disabled 'x' but now I have multiples alerts ...

Comment: I think you'll need to show an example of what you're doing, because this sounds like its a specific issue to how you've set it up, and I'm still not clear how you have multiple alerts (assuming you are setting up multiple alerts somehow).